# Discord.py noughts and crosses

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a noughts and crosses bot in discord.py and most of it is getting called, but the last bit is not
My code so far is:

````
if parts[0] == "-nac":
    global user, usr
    oauth = message.author.name
    user = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=partwelc[1])
    usr = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=oauth)
    if user is not None:
        await message.channel.send(f"{usr.mention} is challenging {user.mention} to naughts and crosses! {user.mention}, to play, do -accept!")
        global playorno
        playorno = 1
else:
    global ll, l
    ll = 0
    l = 0
if playorno == 1:

    if message.author == user:
        playorno = 0
        if parts[0] == "-accept":
            ll = 1
            await message.channel.send(f"{user.mention} has accepted {usr.mention}'s duel request!")
            await usr.send("You are crosses! You are going 1st as you made the request! To play, just simply say, A1 for top right, A2 for top middle etc!")
            await user.send("You are naughts! You are going 2nd as you did not make the request! To play, just simply say, A1 for top right, A2 for top middle etc!")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Request timed out.")
            ll = 0
if ll == "1":
    print("L")
    box1 = None
    box2 = None
    box3 = None
    box4 = None
    box5 = None
    box6 = None
    box7 = None
    box8 = None
    box9 = None
    l = 1
    ll = 0
if parts[0] == "1te":
    print("ok:" parts[0])
    if parts[0] == "A1":
        box1 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "A2" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box2 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "A3" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box3 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "B1" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box4 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "B2" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box5 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "B3" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box6 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "C1" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box7 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "C2" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box8 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")
    if parts[0] == "C3" and message.author.name == usr.name:
        box9 = "X"
        await message.channel.send(f"__| {box1} | {box2} | {box3} |__\n__| {box4} | {box5} | {box6} |__\n__| {box7} | {box8} | {box9} |__")```
````

My problem is that I am getting an output `"ok"` but when I put `"A1"` in the channel, I do not get an output from the bot. Thanks for reading. For

```
print("ok", parts)
```

my output was immediately "1te" as that was what I was testing the bot with as I have no friends in the channel, so to test, instead of if "ll == 1:" I was using: "if parts[0] == "1te":"

Comment: `print("ok")` is wrongly indented, and perhaps you could do `print("ok:", parts[0])` and show us the output? So we can see what `parts` is, and more specifically `parts[0]` which you use to evaluate things. We have no idea what `parts` even is or where it comes from as you left that out. But guessing here that you want to do `if parts[1] == "A1"` since `parts[0]` seams to be `-nac` etc. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Ah, i forgot to say, parts = message.content.split() and I know the print is not indented correctly, that is just to say that I was getting output from that

Comment: Please add the exact content and result from `print("ok:", parts)` or `print("ok:", [parts[0]])` (note the additional `[ ]` around the parts. (And add it to your question, not in the comment section as it helps read it via code blocks :)

Comment: Ok, changed it in the question

Comment: Could you *pleeease* correct your indentations. As there's a bunch of wonky indents. Also `if ll == "1"` will always be `False` as `ll = 0` is integer, but you're comparing against the string `"1"`.

Comment: i meant ll == 1

Comment: Ok, add (in a code block) the following: `print("ok:", parts)` and please use your `A1` logic, don't make things up : ) heh, keep it simple - makes it simpler to help.

Comment: i did do that I put the" print("ok", parts) "and it output ok 1te as that was my testing thing so i put in "1te" and it output "ok 1te", as i said.

Comment: No.. Show the **unfiltered output from the terminal**. Don't interprate or change it. Just, copy - paste and don't change it or write it manually. When asking for help, it's paramount that you don't change any details. and don't change the input values either. In your question, you asked about `A1` and now you changed the input data to `1te`. And I asked you to print a **list**, but you'te saying the output is a string of `ok 1lte` (without `:` all of a sudden, even tho I asked you to do `print("ok:", parts)` which should contain `:` and also a list.. so.. copy.. paste.. don't change anything)

Comment: Not trying to be rude btw, but it's insanely hard to help someone who changes the parameters half way through and doesn't post **exactly** what you ask for. I need that list, not the string, because the list will show hidden characters, spaces and encoding issues. So don't alter anything, give it to us straight.

Comment: ok: ['1te'] is the unfiltered output. Also, just to be clear, I put in 1te to start the process, which should do nothing, then I put in A1 to output the grid

Comment: Ok, I'm voting to close this as there's not enough information in this question then. There's nothing in your code that relates to `1lte` and we're debugging `A1` specific code. So in order to help you, either give us the data where the `OK` part prints with the `A1` scenario.

Comment: I have now edited the post to show what my legitimate testing code is right now